# ByteArrayOutputStream/InputStream losing newline characters on S3 Import

Tags: java, amazon-s3, newline, bytearrayoutputstream, bytearrayinputstream

I have the following code (pseudo code-ish)...

```
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
output.write("something\n".getBytes());
output.write("something\n".getBytes());

ByteArrayOutputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(output.getBytes());
s3.putStream(input);
```

Then when I get the file from s3 it looks like this: somethingsomething.

The newlines are gone!!  I can't figure out why that is happening and internet searches have not been helpful.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: How do you check file?

Comment: Just going to the s3 console and opening it there.  It shows it as a txt file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is common problem with *NIX vs Windows files.

Try : "\r\n" instead of "\n"

```
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
output.write("something\r\n"".getBytes());
output.write("something\r\n"".getBytes());

ByteArrayOutputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(output.getBytes());
s3.putStream(input);
```

Comment: That is a good point.  I'm actually writing that code on a *NIX system and then reading it in Windows.  I'll give that a try, thanks.